# Is case important while parsing JSON using GSON

Tags: java

I am parsing JSON data, and storing the results in a Java object using GSON. My question is, should the fields in the JSON String match the instance variables in the class? Including the class names? For eg,

If this is my JSON string -

```
"telephone":
{
    "landline":"1-818-502 8310"
}
```

Should I have a class as below?

```
public class Telephone 
{
    private String landline;
}
```

The reason why I am asking this is, when I use gson's fromJson(obj), the object doesn't contain any values. It shows all records as null. I am wondering if it is throwing the error due to this.

Please note - This is not the entire code. My JSON data is quite huge, so I can't paste it here. The above telephone string is just one of the many embedded strings within my json string.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem using only the snippet provided?

Comment: That will be hard. Since this is one of the inner classes. I am basically reading data from a URL into a java object, of which the Telephone class is one of the inner classes. I won't be able to read the URL's data into this class.

Comment: well, it appears the default naming policy is the same as java - that is, camel case as a convention (assuming your instantiating [a default `Gson` instance using `new`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) and not using the `GsonBuilder` to customize the naming policy).

Answer (score 1):

1. This is wrong JSON:

   ```
      "telephone":{"landline":"1-818-502 8310"}
   ```

   The JSON objects start with a `{` and end with a `}`. SO, it should be something like

   ```
    {"name": "somename", "telephone":{"landline":"1-818-502 8310"}, ...}
   ```
2. Yes. Attributes in class should have exact same case and character as in the JSON String in case you are using default Gson instance as correctly mentioned by Eliran. Please note that you must have attributes just having getter/setter and not attribute wouldn't work.
3. You mentioned you are using inner class. It may not work with default Gson instance. You may need to use `registerTypeAdapter` like this:

   ```
   gson.registerTypeAdapter(MyType.class, new MyInstanceCreator());
   ```

   refer: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization